# Future Tense - necessary or not?

Tags: future, correlative-conjunctions

Is it correct to write the following sentence:

Maybe some of you are interested and **find** the time to look at it before the training day.

Or do I have to use the will-future in the second part of the sentence:

Maybe some of you are interested and **will find** the time to look at it before the training day.

Comment: Use "will" there. You are referring to the time between the present moment and the upcoming training day, the future.

Comment: Nothing special about _will_; just another modal auxiliary verb. Other modals could be used as well: _.. and can/may/might/could find.._.

Comment: I go with John Lawler

Answer (score 1):

The sentence begins with "may be" (= probability) and expresses the hope that "some... will find the time..."

May be some of you are interested and "will find" the time to look at it before the training day.
Another possibility: "can find"

Answer (score 1):

> *"Maybe some of you are interested and find the time to look at it before the training day."

This is not grammatical.  You have to add "will" or some other auxiliary before "find".  However, it's not obvious why that is so, because both the following are okay,

> Some are interested.
>   Some find the time to do something.

and ordinarily, since both "are interested" and "find the time to do something" are good verb phrases, this would imply that they can be conjoined to form a good verb phrase "are interested and find the time to do something".

Indeed, you can probably find a context where a phrase similar to this last verb phrase could be used:

> Some students are interested in grammar and find the time to work out details of many example sentences.

But in this last example, "find the time ..." refers to a repeated or habitual action, while in your original example, the corresponding phrase refers to an event which is to occur just once.

I have decided that I don't understand the example.